# Dynamic application property and windows service

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

- i am using VS 2010 to build a windows service
- i also attach a setup project with this service
- Now, in the service - i have app.config file that has application property. say the name of the application property is "xyz"
- Now, is there any way we can just send someone else the full blown setup files and after the service has been installed - go the place where the service is installed - configure the application properties (xyz in our case) and then from the computer management, start the service?

Comment: The simple answer is yes, but it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let me take an example to describe what i am looking for.

Comment: Let me take an example to describe what i am looking for. say there is a XML file say pqr.xml and our service consumes data from this xml after it starts. Now, the location of this pqr.xml should be kept dynamic. How do i allow someone to pass the location of this file - i was hoping we could pass it as application property. But the application property should be inputted without the need of Visual studio. So if someone has full blown MSI's installers only - can they configure the setting during or after service installation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd modify the config file using the MSI installer, but it can always modified once it's copied to the local system.  You could write a simple front-end application to modify the config file based on user input and then start the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got to know that we can use a service config file that takes the form myservicename.exe.config but i ran into the following problem now - [Some Services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356040/some-services-stop-automatically-if-they-are-not-in-use-by-other-services)

Thanks all for your inputs!