# Some Services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services

Error "SOME SERVICES STOP AUTOMATICALLY IF THEY ARE NOT IN USE BY OTHER SERVICES" while trying to start a windows service.

I have a service that does not use the windows service config file and uses static properties - it works fine

Now, i make use of app.config file and rebuild my setup project + the service project. Now i install the service and then try to start the service - i get the following error:

SOME SERVICES STOP AUTOMATICALLY IF THEY ARE NOT IN USE BY OTHER SERVICES

Service logs on as local system.

Any input is welcome please! Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is generally the result of one of two things - either (a) your `OnStart()` method is throwing an exception or (b) the `OnStart()` method is not kicking off a thread to do work.

If the problem is (a), then the obvious solution is to debug the service to identify what is going wrong.  At a minimum, put a `try-catch` block around the contents of the `OnStart()` method and log an error to the system event log when an exception occurs.  Then you can see the details in the Windows Event Viewer.

If the problem is (b), then you need to create a thread that actually does something.  The thread needs to be a foreground thread (as opposed to a background thread) to prevent the service from shutting down.  A typical `OnStart()` method looks like this:

```
private System.Threading.Thread _thread;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Uncomment this line to debug...
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        // Create the thread object that will do the service's work.
        _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoWork);

        // Start the thread.
        _thread.Start();

        // Log an event to indicate successful start.
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Successful start.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception.
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // Do the service work here...
}
```

Comment: I have also getting same error and got solution from this answer...
Thanks.

Comment: yes i find error on services into  Windows Event log.

Comment: Update the answer as well brother. Correct the spelling of EventLog....
Helpful answer, thanks @MattDavis

Answer (score 4):

I got this error and it was because the hard drive had filled up. It could be anything that keeps the service from running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error that was due to dll's not being created when running the installUtil.cmd on my serviceInstaller.msi. To fix this I had to include one of these => `<File Id="Interception" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.dll" />` for each dll I was expecting in my project and place it in my Service.wxs file. Like this => `<Fragment><DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationDirectory"><Component Id="ServiceID" Guid="$(var.ServiceGuid)"> *here* <closing tags...>`. And make sure that all the dll's are included in the installers x copy commands :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this by adjusting the service properties.

I noticed that all of the other working services were using "Local System" as "Log On As", but the service having issue was using "Local Service". You can fix this by going to the list of services, right click on desired service, click properties on context menu and then change "Log On As" to "Local system account" if it is not the same as shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while starting the service. when i go and checked application logs,the error is related to telnet.It means the port for telnet(23) is engaged by another service,That time need to go resource manager and check for the service which is using 23 port and disable that service then the respective service able to start without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Search service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Check [this out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2484025/windows-search-service-will-not-start-error-the-windows-search-service).

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, i was using my IP in binding and it got updated after which started getting this exception. Updated it with my host name instead of IP to avoid future case